# Unable to implement loading bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can someone tell me why is this not working? I am puzzled. The site in question: http://goodmoodhostel.com

JS:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
    $("#loading").hide();  
})
```

HTML:

```
<div id="loading">  
    Loading content, please wait..  
    <img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading.." />  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#loading {  
    position:absolute;  
    width:100%;
    height:2000px;  
    top:0px;   
    text-align:center;  
    padding:7px 0 0 0;  
    font:bold 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
z-index:100;
}
```

The problem is the page starts loading despite the fact that it should be hidden by `#loading` div which covers whole body and has higher `z-index` than any other element.

Comment: Your loading div doesn't have a background color, therefore it is transparent (see through). :-)

Comment: Is the CSS defined in an external file? If so, bring it into the main HTML document (and in-line if possible). Browsers will start to render the page before all of the styles are available. External styles take the longest.

Comment: That's not a good practice to ask us to debug a distant site. You should build a minimal example, test it, and after that put it here (and if possible in jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @dystroy Otherwise considered as too localized for SO.

Comment: @KevinB I agree with that.

Comment: @BrianBall As far as I remember - that is not true. It will stop rendering if it will find some script or css file attached. And it will not start rendering until all head css files are loaded

Comment: If it's defined in the head, that is probably true (which is the case now that I know the site), but for external files, it will render before it gets all of the files, then apply the styles later (usually if you want an element hidden when a page loads, you in-line the style so the browser doesn't render it).

Comment: @BrianBall https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering#PutCSSInHead see details section. As it says, `Browsers block rendering a web page until all external stylesheets have been downloaded.`

Answer (score 1):

That's because `jquery.js` isn't found.

You might change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and I humbly apologize for making you "debug a distant site". I am not familiar with policies of SO as much as I should be, apparently. I will try to familiarize myself with it urgently, but I am in horrible hurry to finish this. Sorry again.